# How to effect API Quota extension/increment in API client/Project

Tags: youtube-api, google-data-api

I applied to YouTube for Data API extension/unit increment a while ago. This morning, i got a reply that my request has been granted and my daily units increased to 1,000,000. However, on Google console, my daily quota still reads 10,000 per day. Please how do i effect the increment on my API Client/Project?

Comment: Congratulations on getting a quota increase thats not an easy feet..  Double check that its the project that you applied under and not a different one.   It may take a few days to kick other then that i would contact them if it still doesn't change.   You could try and increase it yourself using the pencil icon.  I cant really remember if i had to do that or if it was automatically increased by google

Comment: "The total quota for 402282485261 is now 1,000, 000 units / day." I got that as part of the message/mail. Now i don't recognize that number, as i don't have a project that bears that number. Could it be a mistake from Google? Trying to edit with the pencil icon didn't work. I guess i should give it a few days and see.